# Does QGIS run on new Microsoft Surface Pro X with ARM arquitecture?

Tags: qgis, arm

I am planning to buy for my company a Microsoft Surface Pro X tablet. I will use it mainly for QGIS, sometimes in the streets, sometimes in the office.

It has windows installed but does QGIS run on new Microsoft Surface Pro X with ARM arquitecture?

Comment: As I know does Microsoft Surface Pro X supports only 32 bit apps at the moment. Since QGIS from 3.18 onwards is only as a 64 bit app available you can run into problems with newer QGIS versions. Microsoft is planing to support also 64bit apps in the future with the Surface Pro X, but you should be aware, that it is always an emulated 64bit mode. So you don't have a guarantee that QGIS will work on it properly. For myself I decided to buy a Lenovo Yoga Duet 7i 13...cheaper, intel i7 processor and real 64bit architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the ARM architecture, you are of course bound to 32bit. When you install QGIS you have to make sure that you use the 32bit version. This is of course much slower and will probably not support all features in the future. It would be better to go for a comparable tablet with a full IntelCore cpu, such as the Surface Pro 7.

Here you can find all downloads for all supported OS (inkl. 32/64bit and mobile devices): https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/download.html